# hide and show input - Dynamic Form Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I have dynamic forms wbraganca working on Yii2, but I need to add a small function to hide a field when selecting a droplist option and do that in every new dynamic form. Currently I can do it, but only in the first dynamic way.

_Form

```
<? = $form->field ( $modelQuestion , "[{$indexQuestion}]question" )->dropDownList (
        ArrayHelper::map ( QuestType::find ()->all () , 'id' , 'description' ) , [
    'prompt' => '-- Select Question --'
] );
?>
<?= $form->field ( $modelQuestion , "[{$indexQuestion}]add-options" )->label ( false )->textInput ( [ 'maxlength' => true ] ) ?>
```

Js

```
$("#questions-0-question").change(function(){

    var op=document.getElementById("questions-0-question");

    if (op.selectedIndex == 3) {
            $('#add-options').hide();
        }else {
            $('#add-options').show();
       }

  });
```

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Comment: what look like you have a view `create` and you are loading the `_form` and `form-opc` view? if that s correct the script should work if you will include it on top of the `create` view

Comment: hi,the "create" function is in the "controllerEvaluation", while the views is only _form and _form-opc, what I want to get the name of the model and the index of the current row, which in this case is dynamicform_inner of the _form-opc view.

Comment: Once I have them I want to add it inside the js so that each time I select the option "sustain" these options are hidden.

Comment: i was not talking about the `actionCreate` but the `create.php` view file which is loaded using the line , `return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelQuestion' => (empty($modelQuestion)) ? [new Question] : $modelQuestion,
            'modelsOpc' => (empty($modelsOpc)) ? [[new Option]] : $modelsOpc
        ]);` and more over it qualifies to be a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to target the `.dynamicform-wrapper` which is holding the dynamic form inputs that you add on runtime, you should use event delegation which will automatically take care of the newly added input.

To detect the relevant field you can use the regular expression to extract the model and index of the current row which is appended to the dynamic inputs in the format of `modelname-index` means if i have a question model being loaded in the dynamic form then the input `question_title` will have an id `question-1-question_title` and then so on.

Use the expression

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+)\-([0-9]+)/g
```

to match the model name and append it to the relevant input you are trying to hide.

Add below code on top of your view

```
$JS = <<< JS

        $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("change","select",function(){
                var id=$(this).attr("id");
                var optionsInput=id.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)\-([0-9]+)/g)[0]+'-add-options';

                if ($(this).val()== 3) {
                    $('#'+optionsInput).hide();
                }else {
                    $('#'+optionsInput).show();
               }

        });

JS;

$this->registerJs($JS, yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Thanks, It was just what I was looking for, Now I'm trying to hide or eliminate the options of the question at the selecting the type of question, for example I'have a file "_form" where I declare the questions and a file "_form-opc" where are the options, what I want to do is that when selecting the type of question "justify" does not show me to add options, I tried with the example that you put me but I do not know how to get "modelname-index" from the "_form-opc" file, could you guide me how I could eliminate the options ?

Comment: it would be better if you add the controller action and the view file where you are loading both of these views  @MiguelAngelAyalaPajuelo , or add the script inside top of the main view where you are including `_form` and `_frm-opc`

Comment: Hi, modify and I included my code in the question, @Muhammad

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your selector is too broad.  `$('#add-options')` is asking the entire DOM for an element with the ID = 'add-options'.

Using an ID selector (#) will only get one object back, since ID's are expected to be unique. To select multiple objects you need to use another form of selector, like a class name selector (.some_class_name).

For my example below, I only really need to know the question that changed, and then I'm going to use that with a container div to control the context in which the rest of the DOM selection happens.

You should wrap your `question` and `add-options` fields in a div wrapper and assign a known class `question-container` to the wrapper like this:

```
<div class='question-container'>
    <select id="question-1" class="question">...</select>
    <input type="text" id="add-options" />
</div>
<div class='question-container'>
    <select id="question-2" class="question">...</select>
    <input type="text" id="add-options" />
</div>
```

NOTE - I've also added the `class="question"` to each of the question select boxes.  This makes wiring up the questions easier.

Then you can add this javascript, and it will work for all questions on the page (admittedly verbose, but for clarity):

```
// Find all select boxes with the class 'question', and wire up the change event
$("select.question").change(function(){
    // Reference the current question select box to a variable for clarity.
    var question  = this;   

    // This retrieves the closest container with the class '.question-container'
    var container = $(question).closest('.question-container');  

    // Finds the add-options field inside the container. Note, our context is the container, not the entire DOM.
    var addOptions = container.find('#add-options');

    // Hide or show the add options based on the index that is selected.
    if (question.selectedIndex == 3) {
        addOptions.hide();
    } else { 
        addOptions
    }
}
```

I wrote this code from the hip, it has not been tested.

Comment: it is technically wrong to have multiple inputs with the same `id` and dynamic-form extension used y the OP does not create the inputs with similar `id` , and you can get the value of the dropdown using `$(this).val()` simply and you are not using event delegation so this is not going to work for the dynamically added elements

Comment: He's using the selected Index, not the value, I was attempting to keep within the context of his design.  Also, I reference the fact that ID's are supposed to be Unique.